# Can someone spot the errors in my code? I don't know what part am I missing and what I messed up

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

sample output that I want:

```
chocolate bar   $1.00
skittles        $1.20
marshmellows    $5.00
candy-cane      $0.90
```

the output I got:

```
░"@  $1.00
░"@  $1.20
░"@  $5.00
░"@  $0.90
```

the code I made:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void ShowMenu();
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    float price[4][1]= {1,1.2,5,0.9};
    char snack[4][20];
    
    ShowMenu(price, i, j, snack);
    
    return 0;
}

void ShowMenu(float price[4][1], int i, int j, char snack[4][20])
{
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        for (j=0;j<1;j++)
            {
            if(i==0)
            snack[0][20]=="chocolate bar" ;
            else if(i==1)
            snack[1][20]=="skittles"  ;
            else if(i==2)
            snack[2][20]=="marshmellows"  ;
            else if(i==3)
            snack[3][20]=="candy-cane"  ;
            printf("%s  RM%.2f\n", snack, price[i][j]);
            }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of having a 2D array where one dimension is only `[1]`, and a loop that executes only once.

Comment: Yuo cannot assign to `snack[0][20]` ... **`snack[0][20]` does not exist**. `snack[0]` has 20 elements: `snack[0][0]`, `snack[0][1]`, ..., `snack[0][19]` and each of those elements **is a single character**. (you want `snack[0][0] = 'c'; snack[0][1] = 'h', /*...*/ snack[0][14] = '\0';` or `strcpy(snack[0], "chocolate bar");`)

Comment: Please turn on full compiler warnings and begin there. In particular, you can't assign a string in C with `=` (except in initialisation) or compare a string in C with `==`, use `strcmp()`. This looks like a good case for using `struct` with one member `price` and another `snack`.

Comment: Also, the input / output shown is not consistent with that code (RM vs $).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your function prototype has to be ***exactly** the same as your definition!!!
2. It is hard what is the purpose of many variables and parameters. I have stripped down everything not needed

```
void ShowMenu(float price[], char *snack[], int nitems);
int main(void)
{
    float price[4] = {1,1.2,5,0.9};
    char *snack[20] = {"chocolate bar", "skittles", "marshmellows", "candy-cane"};
    
    ShowMenu(price, snack, 4);
    
    return 0;
}

void ShowMenu(float price[], char *snack[], int nitems)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nitems; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\tRM%.2f\n", snack[i], price[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Re “Your function prototype has to be *exactly the same as your definition!!!”: That is not correct. The parameters in the definition are compatible with the arguments after default argument promotion, so the behavior is defined, per C 2018 6.5.2.2 6.

Comment: @EricPostpischil bare in mind the level of this question. For OP the rule of thumb is **they have to be the same** to avoid hard to find for him errors.

Comment: This answer does not explain what was wrong in the original program. It does not even explain why the new program works. Stack Overflow is not supposed to be a service for giving students code; it is supposed to answer questions and present information. This answer fails that.

Comment: @EricPostpischil DV then